# SPFx web part page context does not update when linking between pages

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have added the same SPFx web part to two different site pages. The web part contains links (a href) to both pages and some page related info collected from this.context.pageContext.

When I click on the link in one of the pages to the other page, pageContext does not update and the web part still shows the info related to the page I first visited.

Is it supposed to work this way and does anyone know how to force the web part pagecontext to update when linking between pages with the same web part?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue that is being worked on.  In the meantime, there should be a REST API that you can call - https://tenant/sites/site/web/_api/ComponentContextInfo/?List=%7Bputyour-page-list-guid-overhere%7D

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more how to use this REST API? Which information could be of interest in the REST response in this case?